# graphql is only resolving _id field, other fields are null

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

GraphQL is resolving my title and content properties as null, though the data is definitely being retrieved from the server - the console log in the confirms it. Only the _id property is returned from graphql, this is what I get back from the query `json { listings: [ { _id: '56e6c94f1cf94a7c0a4e22ba', title: null, content: null } ] }` As far as I can tell everything is set up correctly, I also tried giving title and content a GraphQLIDType to rule out the differences it types.

I have a graphql query:

```
query(`
  query findListings {
    listings(offset: 1) {
      _id,
      title,
      content
    }
  }
`).then((json) => {
  console.log('json', json.data)
})
```

my root query type:

```
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    listings: {
      name: 'listings',
      type: new GraphQLList(ListingType),
      args: {
        limit: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        offset: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        }
      },
      resolve(source, args, info) {
        const { fieldASTs } = info
        const projection = getProjection(fieldASTs[0])

        return ListingModel.find({}, projection).then(listing => {
          console.log(listing)
          return listing
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and my "listing type":

```
const ListingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Listing',
  fields: {
    _id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    content: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: what does `console.log(listing)` print?

Comment: This: `[ { content: 'I am the content',
    title: 'Hello and welcome',
    _id: 56e6c94f1cf94a7c0a4e22ba } ]`

Comment: If you are absolutely sure `console.log(listing)` prints that array, then error should be elsewhere. Maybe in your client where you make the query? If you still could not resolve this, consider posting more code that are relevant. This code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Have you tried the query using graphiql?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but had similar problem, when querying for list returns null.

When querying for arrays you'll get an object {key: yourArray}, so it should be:

```
return ListingModel.find({}, projection).then(listing => {
 console.log(listing)
 return {listing: listing}
```